# How to include boolean conditions to python's list comprehension?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension, boolean-logic

**INPUT:**
I have a list of strings with places I can work:

```
ALL_CHANCES = ['I can work in China',
               'I can work in Germany',
               'I can work in Singapore',
               'I can work in Norway']
```

I have another list of strings with places better not to work at:

```
HIGH_TAX = ['Germany',
            'Norway']
```

**OUTPUT:**
I am looking for a simple list comprehension one-liner to filter list 1 for items that have substrings occurring in list 2:

```
GOOD_CHANCES = ['I can work in China',
                'I can work in Singapore']
```

**CHALLENGE:**

However, when I do

```
GOOD_CHANCES  = [item for item in ALL_CHANCES
                      if (not any(word for word in HIGH_TAX) in item)]
```

I yield the following error:

```
'<string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

**How to include boolean conditions to python's list comprehension?**

Comment: The backslash is unnecessary and the `== True` seems unnecessary as well.

Comment: the backslash is for illustrative purposes since people tend not to read code that requires scrolling to the right

Comment: No, you can put a linebreak there if I'm not confused. The opening square brackets indicate to Python that until the closing one everything belongs together. See e.g. the definition of `HIGH_TAX` above. ;)

Comment: Das hat eine Zeit gedauert bis ich voll umrissen hab was genau du meinst^^ danke Ulrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simpler as follows:

```
GOOD_CHANCES  = [item for item in ALL_CHANCES \
                  if not any(word in item for word in HIGH_TAX)]
```

In your solution, `not any(word for word in HIGH_TAX)` is evaluating to a `bool` which is then being compared to the string `item`. Instead as shown above, you can include the substring check in the `any` method call itself

It might also be clearer to use the `filter` method:

```
filter(lambda item: not any(word in item for word in HIGH_TAX), ALL_CHANCES)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is:

```
[item for item in ALL_CHANCES if item.split()[-1] not in HIGH_TAX]
```

This is assuming that all the countries are at the end of the sentence.

It the country may be present anywhere, you might try:

```
[item for item in ALL_CHANCES if not any( h in item for h in HIGH_TAX )  ]
```

Comment: as usual, the country is not always at the same position - anyways, thanks for your input